# Break on any javascript code in WebStorm/PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, breakpoints, phpstorm, webstorm, javascript-debugger

I can debug a javascript web page running on a local Apache server under PhpStorm just fine but I'd like to go into debugging, step-by-step mode whenever some javascript code is triggered. For example, when I click a button in the browser, I would like PhpStorm to stop executing the javascript and allow me to go through it step-by-step.

Is it possible to do this without putting breakpoints in all javascript functions?

Comment: are you debugging in chromebug/firebug, or are you debugging your js in PhpStorm itself?

Comment: When I click Debug in PhpStrom, Chrome opens with a top bar "PhpStorm is debugging this tab..."

Comment: Ok you should just be able to click on the side of the edit window next to the line numbers in phpStorm to add a little red breakpoint circle to the line of code you want to break on, the same as if you wanted to add a breakpoint in the chromebug script view.
Your question was a little bit strange because you said "I would like PhpStorm to stop executing", but it's not PhpStorm executing, it's the Chrome browser. PhpStorm is just connecting to it's debugger and giving you a view of it.

Comment: I see, thank you. Still, is there a way for the Chrome debugger to automatically pause whenever it would start executing Javascript code without me having to add a breakpoint everywhere in the chromebug view?

Comment: oh, yes sort of. In the chrome debugger, go to the sources tab and click the little pause icon on the right hand side. Then next time any javascript executes it will pause. Press it again to play through your code then put it back on pause.

Answer (score 0):

You may try wrap the event handler like so:

```
<button id='mybutton'>Break on click</button>
<button id='mybutton2'>Break on mouseover</button>

<script>

  var b = document.querySelector('#mybutton');
  var b2 = document.querySelector('#mybutton2');

  b.onclick = function(){
     console.log('do stuff');   
  }

  b2.onmouseover = function(){
     console.log('do other stuff');   
  } 

  function breakon(evt){
    return function(){  
        console.log('breaking');
        debugger;
        evt();
    }
  }

  // break on different events
  b.onclick = breakon(b.onclick);
  b2.onmouseover = breakon(b2.onmouseover);

</script>
```